# Can anyone help implementing Nuxt.js Google Tag Manager with function based id

Tags: google-tag-manager, nuxt.js

I installed and add this code to my nuxt.config.js and it works perfectly fine. (Link to [package](https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/tree/master/packages/google-tag-manager))

```
  modules: [
   ['@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager', { id: 'GTM-XXXXXXX' }],
  ]
```

Now I am trying to implement instead of a static ID a function which will return an ID.

I tried to add this lines into my nuxt.config. js but it is not working. Obviously I have to put it somewhere else or so...

**This is what I tried**

**nuxt.config.js**

```
const code = '1234567'
id: () => {
  return 'GTM-' + code
}

export default {
...

modules: [
   ['@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager', { id: id }],
  ]
...
}
```

What would be the correct way implementing this?

I would like to do something like that at the end.

```
modules: [
   ['@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager', { 
       id: ({ req }) => {
         if (req.headers.referer == "exmple.com")
           return 'GTM-156'
         if (req.headers.referer == "exmple.it")
           return 'GTM-24424'
         if (req.headers.referer == "exmple.es")
           return 'GTM-2424'
       }
   }]]
```

**EDIT:**
I solved my problem by rewriting the whole module. It is not possible to use this Module because it is loaded only on build time. I rewrote the module and moved the code into nuxtServerInit.

nuxtServerInit is called on each request (modules only onetime). In the request I asked from which domain the request is coming. Depending on the domain I add different google-tag-manager id's to the head and the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

From package docs:

```
modules: [
   ['@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager', { 
       id: () => {
          return axios.get('http://example.com/')
            .then(({ data }) => {
              return data.gtm_id
            })
       }
   }]]
```

You can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` inside function which will return an ID

**Edit 1**

To put the gtm id, depending on req.headers.referer you need to provide context to the function returning the id. This can be done in middleware

See how it works here
https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/blob/master/packages/google-tag-manager/plugin.js

**Edit 2**

As far as I understand your question, it will not work to have a query context in the config.

Look at i18n middleware: request.locale - > store - > update modules (router, vuetify, moment, etc.)
https://nuxtjs.org/examples/i18n/

~/middleware/gtm.js

```
export default function ({ app, store }) {
  // app.$gtm contains id, you can set another from store
}
```

don't forget to add middleware to the page

page.vue

```
export default {
  middleware: ['gtm']
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your code is working but I want to change the ID depending on the calling domain. So I have only one instance of nuxt which is serving different domains. Within process.env.NODE_ENV I can not see the request url or domain, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Look at the edited answer, you need to write middleware that will change the id on request.

Comment: Thank you! I also edited my question. Can I add the context somehow to the id? I also store the hostname in the store. But I am not sure how to access it from there.

Comment: what do you want to show me exactly with the i18n example. I can't follow you.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. But how can I access the app.$gtm?  I can not see $gtm in my app?

Comment: I've added an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253819/nuxtserverinit-add-google-tag-manager-scripts-to-head-an-body/59777309#59777309) which is very similar and might be useful to people here. It takes a different approach by creating my own plugin.